# How to get the column name on clearing the filter in AGGRID?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a requirement to the clear the filters saved. For that I need the column name.

```
onFilterChanged: function(event){
var newObj = {}
 newObj =  gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();}
```

Here I am getting the filter details along with column name when I set the filter. But how to get the column name if I clear the filter

`gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();` is empty if I clear a filter.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Can you please post the full context of the code? Without that, all I can help is to ask you to check gridOptions.getAllGridColumns(). This will return all the columns in order of the columns that are presented in the grid. Also, you may look up to the Columns API for ag-grid at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/.
Cheers!!

Comment: Added the changes, If i clear filter i need the particular cleared filter column name.gridOptions.getAllGridColumns() will return all column . I need filtered column

Answer (score 0):

Well the moment we remove the filter condition, ag grid sets filter model to null thus `gridOptions.api.getFilterModel();` returns nothing.

To remember which filter was touched(through UI or programmtically) we need to listen to `onFiltermodified` event since ag grid first modifies the filter(when we remove the conditions) and then applies it(change). so you can listen to this event and can save columnId in some variable since `onFilterChange` event follows this event.

The only scenario when this workaround will fail is when you are setting/clearing set filter programmatically because ag grid skips `filterModified` event and directly calls `Filterchanged` event. but i hope if you are doing something programmatically then you already have the list of columns on which you are adding or removing filters.

```
    onFilterModified : function(params){
     // note : set filter does not trigger this event if filtering is done using api
      filtercolId = params.column.colId; // save the colID
    },
    onFilterChanged : function(params){
    //if filter is removed then gridOptions.api.getFilterModel(); will return empty so 
    //use filtercolId which was stored during filterModified event.
    console.log(params);
    }
```